# How to access a DIV inside a iframe from a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access a div id="mnuGrp" that resides inside a child iframe(id="iframe2) from the parent window within the `document.ready()` section but unsure how to access this child div in the parent inorder to apply fadein and fadeout calls.

I want to be used within the following call:

```
$(' ???? ').click(function(){ etc
```

where "????" is my means to access the child div within the iframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're asking in a jQuery context specifically:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#iframe2').contents().find('div#mnuGrp').fadeIn('slow');
    // or whichever effect you prefer
});
```

Note that you will likely be constrained by the Same Origin Policy with respect to the main page and the frame source.

Comment: The Origin policy would mainly be X-Frames where your accessing content on a frame that's not abiding to your domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the div in this way: `window.frames[framename].document.getElementById("mnuGrp")`

Comment: thanks Kangkan but how would I use this inside a document.ready call, such as $(' ???? ').click(function(){ etc

Comment: I imagine $(window.frames[framename]).find('#mnuGrp') would work

Comment: jQuery: for people who don't understand JavaScript.

Comment: Yea.. because the Javascript language is that well written everyone needs to understand there silly mistakes and choose not to use a mask for the language :/

Comment: `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`.

Comment: Kangkan: No need to apologise. I've edited the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone loves this `contents().find()` not sure why.
jQuery isn't required. But if you wanted to use jQuery:

```
$("#mnuGrp", $("#iframe2")[0].contentWindow.document).click();
```