# getting a div from an iframe pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this piece of code to copy the value of on div to another. The problem is that the "listprice" div is inside the iframe that is being loaded by the page that has v4-25 in it. Do you think there is a way to actually acces the "listprice" from that iframe?

I can't use any library for that, it has to be pure javascript.

```
var string = document.getElementById('v4-25').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('listprice').innerHTML = string;
```

Thank you,

H

Comment: only if the iframe is on the same domain. is it?

Comment: Libraries _are_ pure Javascript.  They're just pure Javascript written by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.frames[framename].document.getElementById("listprice")
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question [How to Access a DIV inside a iframe from a Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994639/how-to-access-a-div-inside-a-iframe-from-a-parent) See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994639/how-to-access-a-div-inside-a-iframe-from-a-parent/2994653#2994653) answer, it demonstrates how to access the element across an iframe using plain JavaScript.